# TypeError: createSlice is not a function from vitest

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, vitest

I am building a tic-tac-toe game in react with redux and trying to use vitest for testing. I have setup board slice and the store but when trying to run my first test i get the error below

```
⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯ Failed Suites 1 ⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯

 FAIL  src/slices/board/reducers/updateMoveReducer.test.js [ src/slices/board/reducers/updateMoveReducer.test.js ]
TypeError: createSlice is not a function
 ❯ src/slices/board/board.js:11:20
      9| };
     10| 
     11| const boardSlice = createSlice({
       |                    ^
     12|  name: 'board',
     13|  initialState,
 ❯ src/slices/board/reducers/updateMoveReducer.test.js:1:31

⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯⎯[1/1]⎯

 Test Files  1 failed (1)
      Tests  no tests
   Start at  13:36:13
   Duration  1.27s (transform 371ms, setup 0ms, collect 0ms, tests 0ms)
```

Here is my gameStore code

```js
import boardReducer from './slices/board/board';
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const gameStore = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        board: boardReducer,
    },
});
```

Here is the board slice

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { updateMoveReducer } from './reducers/updateMoveReducer';
const initialState = {
    tiles: [
        [undefined, undefined, undefined],
        [undefined, undefined, undefined],
        [undefined, undefined, undefined],
    ],
};

const boardSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'board',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        updateMove: updateMoveReducer,
    },
});

export const { updateMove } = boardSlice.actions;
export default boardSlice.reducer;
```

Here is the updateMoveReducer currently.

```js
export const updateMoveReducer = (state, action) => {
    return state;
};
```

I have the store setup with Provider in the app and can see that the slice is setup correctly when using the redux chrome dev tool.

[redux chrome dev tool screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plRNV.png)

tried running the following test that gave the error.

```js
import { updateMove } from '../board';
import { gameStore } from '../../../gameState';
import { expect, it, describe } from 'vitest';

describe('updateMoveReducer', () => {
    it('should update the tiles array with the move', () => {
        const player = 'x';
        const move = { x: 0, y: 0 };
        gameStore.dispatch(updateMove({ player, move }));
        const state = gameStore.getState().board;
        expect(state.tiles[move.x][move.y]).toBe(player);
    });
});
```

Comment: Please see https://github.com/vitest-dev/vitest/issues/2509 mentioning a default export problem for versions of vitest up to 0.26.22, but fixed in 0.26.23 - just grab the latest version now and you'll be fine.

Comment: I upgraded to the last version version `0.27.0` and still have the issue personally.